# Is it possible to have a template struct array with different types?

Tags: c++, templates, struct

I'm not entirely sure how to phrase the question, but a quick explanation is the following:
I would like a data structure that has its descriptions and then a bunch of attributes which can be of any data type.

For example:

```
template <class T>
struct attributeStruct
{
    std::string name;
    T *value;
};
```

And then a struct that uses this in something of the following manner:

```
struct dataStructure
{
    std::string name;
    std::string description;
    std::string type;
    attributeStruct<...> **attribute
};
```

Where I don't want the ... to be a fixed type, but is added as different attributes are added.

Is this possible?

Comment: look through "type list" in metaprogramming, i think it can provide you needed functionality

Comment: How about `std::tuple`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer - not possible with template as you've shown them.
Template classes have no relationship with each other.

In order to have a list (array, map, whatever) of different classes you should use inheritance.

The base class can have (virtual) functions like getName(). A getValue() function is a problem since the base class is not aware of the type of the value, you'll need to cast the base pointer to a derived class pointer first. If you declare at least 1 virtual function in the base class you could safely use dynamic_cast<>() to cast to the derived class (e.g. from a global getAttributeValue() function.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
template <class T>
struct dataStructure
{
    std::string name;
    std::string description;
    std::string type;
    attributeStruct<T> **attribute;
};
```

Edit: so you want a heterogeneous array of attributes.  I suggest a variant type, like this:

```
struct dataStructure
{
    std::string name;
    std::string description;
    std::string type;
    std::vector<boost::variant<attributeStruct<int>, attributeStruct<double> > > **attribute;
};
```

You can have many types inside the variant<>, and the variant class with let you store any of them in each "slot" of the vector.

Comment: This way of doing it gets back to the original problem.  Maybe I asked the question in a confusing manner.

I would like a data structure which has attributes of different types, not just a list/array of the same type.

Comment: I like that, but is there a way to do it without using the boost library?

Comment: Sure, you can look at their code and do the same thing.  A common term for this sort of thing is "discriminated union."  You could store void* and an enum which tells you the type, and you'll end up fairly similar to what Boost would give you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem is old and has known solutions. This is up to you to judge the pros and cons according to your current needs:

- Array (or container) of boost::any or boost::variant
- Enum-based coding (one id for registered type), so you have enum value and PVOID as actual data to be parsed later
- Restrict the list of possible types to "safe types" like OLE Automation does